# Unable to stream the UDP on the internet

Tags: networking, router, vlc-media-player

I am using the VLC media player on windows 10.

When I used the file and stream using the HTTP on port 9000 it worked perfectly. I have port forwarding setup on the Router for both ports for the IP address of my windows 10 laptop on port 9000.

LOCAL IP : 192.168.0.7

So when I used the Http://<"ISP public IP">>:9000 
on the same WINDOWS LAPTOP , It worked perfectly.

ISP Public IP : 76.XXX.XXX.XXX

B)

NOW, I tried to use the same for UDP streaming

I chose the file & then selected UDP . Then I provided the IP address 
224.0.0.0 
PORT : 9000

Then without transcoding & Just selected the All Elemental stream.

Trying to play on same computer

udp://192.168.0.7@224.0.0.0:9000

It plays as 
udp://224.0.0.0:9000
on the local computer.

But when I use the following
udp://<<"ISP Public IP">>@224.0.0.0:9000
Nothing works .... :(

PLEASE HELP ,.. what should I do so that I could play the UDP stream from internet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Tried again based on suggestion from Ed..still not able to get the UDP exposed.

[image]
[image]

AS per the internet port .. It shows as opened by ISP for port 9000.

The FIREWALL rule is opened for both TCP and UDP. I selected "BOTH" in router while opening the port for FIREWALL port.

It works locally to play on UDP
[image]

[image: HOW TO PERFORM NORMAL UDP?]

Comment: It’s super unlikely you’re equipped (ISP and otherwise) to receive multicast traffic from the internet.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB but how can I check if ISP is blocking UDP?

Comment: Your ISP is not blocking UDP. The problem here is that you’re trying to do something with [Multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast). Multicast is not usually used on the internet. Perhaps you could include in your question what you’re hoping to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to stream the file and access via UDP protocol. No need for multicast but I am ok with unicast.

Comment: Tried with various options .. Still no luck to play UDP Streaming on Internet.. Please help.

Comment: Tried with 238.1.3.1 on port 9000 to stream via VLC from Laptop running windows 10 ( with local IP  192.168.0.7) . The Router firewall is opened for both UDP and TCP on port 9000. When I try to open the UDP from Internet .. I don't get any response.

Comment: I have attached the snapshot as well above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not trying to just use UDP streaming (which would most likely work perfectly), you are trying to use UDP **multicast** streaming. This is a very important difference.

Multicast is a method, by which a **single sender** can talk one-way to **multiple receivers**. It is initiated by using special IP adresses (224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255), that are not normally used on the internet.

In a flat LAN this poses not many problems: The sent packets will arrive at all connected PCs via the switch and the PCs then can pick those they want and assemble the stream from them.

In a network with routers, this naive approach no longer works: It is physically impossible to transport all packets from all senders to all possible receivers, so that they can pick those that they want.

This is, why most multicast traffic doesn't cross router boundaries - only if all the routers between a receiver and a sender have a mechanism to agree on which multicast packets to transport (again: transporting all is not feasable) can they be delivered. The most common mechanism is `IGMP` (but others exist). I do not know any ISPs providing IGMP for their residential or SMB customers.

Absent such a mechanism, the packets for such a multicast stream will simply not arrive at your Internet connection, so no setting in your home router can make them visible.

If you control the sender, you can configure it to use unicast (i.e. "normal" UDP) to the public IP adress of your internet connection: Then your port forwards will work with a VNC stream designator of `udp://@:9000`.

If you do not control the sender, you can not use this sort of streaming.

Comment: I am the sender and using the VLC.. How can I do "normal UDP" you mentioned. I don't want to perform Multicast over internet. 
1. Local Laptop from where I am broadcasting using VLC media player ( 192.168.0.7)
2. Public IP address ( 76.xx.xx.xxx) 
3. Router port forwarding already done (Image enclosed above) in original post for PORT 9000 ( both TCP and UDP). 

I don't see the option how to avoid multicast.. What IP address should I put when I choose the UDP in the VLC ? I believe the port number is 9000 that is correct but IP Address which I am putting is MAIN part. 

Please help.

Comment: As I said: Stream to your public IP address. So in VLC use udp://76.xx.xx.xxx:9000 as stream target designator. This means: 76.xx.xx.xxx in the first box, 9000 in the second box.

Comment: And on the LAN: use udp://192.168.0.7:9000 as stream target designator.

Comment: Thanks @Eugen Rieck   I am able to stream  udp://76.xx.xx.xxx:9000 but cannot play from internet. Although I am able to play udp://@:9000 and it plays locally. How can I play the VLC from my phone iOS App .. When I tried  udp://76.xx.xx.xxx:9000 it didn't opened any stream.

Comment: As I said: The VLC stream designator in the player should be `udp://@:9000`

Answer (score 0):

The address you are using 224.0.0.0 is local. See [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address) for multicast addresses.

Set up port forwarding like you did for port 9000 tcp (but this time for udp). And then access the udp stream with the public IP, no the multicast one.

Comment: Tried that just now but still the same issue..

Comment: I must be missing something critical in routing.

Answer (score 0):

swap the IP addresses around. "UDP://[local ip]@[public ip]:[port]"

it is searching for "private IP locations @ public ip locations:public port"

the way you have formed your argument it is seeking a non existant IP to retrieve info from.